# nav-stack at large but horizontal below 768px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using TBS, I've got three columns, nav-stacked in the left, content in the middle, and twitter in the right. What I want to achieve is for the nav to go from stacked on large resolution, then go to horizontal on 768 or below, and then stacked again when the menu toggle appears.

Below is the html I'm using, and I'm just using the standard Boostrap three stylesheet.

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                            class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px">
                        <li><a href="#Fencing">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Fencing">Beers and Ales</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Fencing">Eating</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Fencing">What's On</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Fencing">Find Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Fencing">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if its possible with bootsrap css but if you're open to using Jquery then you might be able to achieve it by removing and adding classes based on the width.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).resize(function () 
{ if ($(window).width() <= 1000) 
{ if ($(".nav").hasClass("nav-stacked")) 
{ $('.nav').removeClass('nav-stacked'); } 
} else 
{ if (!$(".nav").hasClass("nav-stacked")) 
{ $('.nav').addClass('nav-stacked'); 
} } 
});</script>' 


   <nav class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                            class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px">
                        <li><a href="#Fencing">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Fencing">Beers and Ales</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Fencing">Eating</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Fencing">What's On</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Fencing">Find Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Fencing">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

http://www.bootply.com/uK0UrlBTKL

Comment: tried th following before the </form> but it didn't work: ' <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(window).resize(function () {

             if ($(window).width() <= 768) {

                 if ($(".nav").hasClass("nav-stacked")) {
                     $('.nav').removeClass('nav-stacked');
                 }

             } else {
                 if (!$(".nav").hasClass("nav-stacked")) {
                     $('.nav').addClass('nav-stacked');
                 }
             }

         });</script>'

Comment: @Marodo I have updated my example. Copy this into a blank html file and run and you will see it working. I've changed the value to be 1000 for demonstration purposes

Comment: @Marodo also this is just an example to go from stacked to horizontal  when the value is less than 768( my example 1000). You will have to expand to jump back to stacked when menu toggle appears. Its an example to get you started

Comment: Thanks @mjroodt, that worked, and I got it to go verticle again by adding the further code 

'<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).resize(function () {
            if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
                if (!$(".nav").hasClass("nav-stacked")) {
                    $('.nav').addClass('nav-stacked');
                }
            } else {
                if ($(".nav").hasClass("nav-stacked")) {
                    $('.nav').removeClass('nav-stacked');
                }
            }
        });</script>'